# How to use Django foreign key sets in queries?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a `Question` model and a `Response` model, which contains a foreign key to a `Question`.

I can get all of the responses for a given question with `question.response_set`

I want to do something to the effect of

```
Question.objects.exclude(response_set=None)
```

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Question.objects.exclude(response__isnull=True)
```

should return only questions with responses

Comment: hm, q = Question.objects.exclude(response__isnull=True).exclude(response__skipped=True) returns a slightly different number of questions than        questions = Response.objects.exclude(skipped=True).distinct('question__id').values_list('question__id', flat=True)

       print len(questions)

       index = randint(1,len(questions))

       qid = questions[index]

       question = Question.objects.get(pk=qid)

why do you think that is?